# Use MAX and MIN on a custom group Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have 2 tables - prod_items and items. In table prod_items one prod_id can have many item_ids. In table items each item has a price, price_code, date when price started and date when price ended. Create table and inserts are :

```
create table items (item_id varchar2(10),
                    price number,
                    price_code varchar2(5),
                    valid_from date,
                    valid_to   date );
                         
create table prod_item (prod_id varchar2(10),
                        item_id varchar2(10) );
                        
insert into prod_item values ('A001','A001 LG 40');
insert into prod_item values ('A001','A001 LG 42');
insert into prod_item values ('A001','A001 LG 44');
insert into prod_item values ('A001','A001 R 40');
insert into prod_item values ('1234','1234 LB 38');
insert into prod_item values ('1234','1234 LB 40');
insert into prod_item values ('1234','1234 LB 42');

insert into items values ('A001 LG 40',33, 'ATG', '01-OCT-2020','03-JAN-2021');
insert into items values ('A001 LG 42',48, 'ATG', '01-OCT-2020','03-NOV-2020');
insert into items values ('A001 LG 44',41, 'ATG', '01-OCT-2020','26-NOV-2020');
insert into items values ('A001 RB 40',78, 'ATG', '01-OCT-2020','03-NOV-2020');

insert into items values ('A001 LG 40',33, 'ATG', '01-OCT-2020','03-JAN-2021');
insert into items values ('A001 LG 42',48, 'ATG', '01-OCT-2020','03-NOV-2020');
insert into items values ('A001 LG 44',41, 'ATG', '01-OCT-2020','26-NOV-2020');
insert into items values ('A001 RB 40',78, 'ATG', '01-OCT-2020','03-NOV-2020');

insert into items values ('A001 LG 40',33, 'ATG', '01-OCT-2020','03-JAN-2021');
insert into items values ('A001 LG 42',42, 'ATG', '03-NOV-2020','02-DEC-2020');
insert into items values ('A001 LG 44',41, 'ATG', '01-OCT-2020','26-NOV-2020');
insert into items values ('A001 RB 40',70, 'ATG', '03-NOV-2020','07-DEC-2020');

insert into items values ('A001 LG 40',33, 'ATG', '01-OCT-2020','03-JAN-2021');
insert into items values ('A001 LG 42',48, 'ATG', '02-DEC-2020','17-DEC-2020');
insert into items values ('A001 LG 44',39, 'ATG', '26-NOV-2020','15-DEC-2020');
insert into items values ('A001 RB 40',78, 'ATG', '07-DEC-2020','24-JAN-2021');

insert into items values ('A001 LG 40',33, 'ATG', '01-OCT-2020','03-JAN-2021');
insert into items values ('A001 LG 42',48, 'XYZ', '17-DEC-2020','03-JAN-2021');
insert into items values ('A001 LG 44',41, 'ATG', '15-DEC-2020','11-JAN-2021');
insert into items values ('A001 RB 40',78, 'ATG', '07-DEC-2020','24-JAN-2021');
```

I want to run max (valid_from) and min(valid_to). Obviously MAX and MIN will need GROUP BY. But is there any way of custom defining a group in Oracle I want the group to be 4 item_ids of the prod_id A001. Please find the expected output :

[image]

Can anyone please help in how to achieve this?

EDIT : Added a new snip of expected output. 4 item_ids have to be one group.

Comment: What is `PROD_validto` and `PROD_validfrom`? Where did they come from?

Comment: As all items belong to the same product ('A001') there will be only one MAX valid_from for all 20 items and only one MIN valid_to for all 20 items. How do you distinguish between the 5 sets of 4 records?

Comment: You specification is very ambiguous . Can you explain how you got the dates in the table you show?

Comment: @astentx - PROD_validfrom and PROD_validto are the dates to get after the MAX and MIN are applied on valid_from and valid_to columns. Guess I should have removed valid_from and valid_to columns from the snip. I guess thats what causing the confusion. I will edit the post now.

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk - Thats the difficulty I am facing. I have already informed the user that this is not possible in Oracle SQL but my lead insisting me to get it done. Also I only gave example of A001 because if I give another 20-25 records for other products then someone might not look at it. Anyways I will add lines for other product in the example

Comment: @gsalem - The 1st 5 columns in the snip already exist in the table. But in order to show the desired output I used the last 2 columns. By the way thats not the output from a query. Its the data from excel. Because I do not know how to group by different ids in Oracle. I very well know MAX(valid_from) group by item_id [select item_id, max(valid_from) from items group by item_id;] will return max(valid_from) of each item_id and not a group which consists of 4 item_ids.

Comment: when you say group of 4 item_ids, how are these 4 rows identified? same item_id, ....

Comment: @gsalem - each group should be of A001 LG 40, A001 LG 42, A001 LG 44 and A001 RB 40 - thats what the business demands. I updated the post with a new snip that shows each group in different colour. I have no clue how to do such a group in Oracle.

Comment: Can you explain how you got these dates? I mean why in the first 4 rows you have 3 Nov 2020 in the last column?

Comment: Is it ok if added another snip of the logic business user has? Because 500 odd characters in comment box wont be enough. But in short - if you look at the insert statements above and take the MIN of valid_to date of 1st 4 rows You get 3-NOV-20